# Shell Script Display having trouble, need assistance

Tags: linux, shell, grep

i got this code below , which is to search for a book when the author field is empty. and it will print out the number of matching and it will print out the number of matching line and show the all the details of the book. But i have a issue with the information that is displayed if i run this code now it will show in the terminal

some of the sample input is shown below

```
The Hunger Games:Suzanne Collins:10:1:50
The Hunger Games:fake author:1:1:1
```

and what was printed with the code i used is shown below

```
Found 2 Records
The Hunger Games
The Hunger Games    Suzanne Collins
Fake Author $10
1   50
1   25
1
```

i wish for the out put to become

```
 Found 2 records
 The Hunger Games, Suzanne Collins, $10, 1, 50
 The Hunger Games, Fake Author, $1, 1, 1
```

Hope someone is able to help me with this. Thanks

```
function search_book 
   {

       echo "Enter Title: "
       read title
       echo "Enter Author: "
       read author
       result_title=$(grep -ise "$title\:" BookDB.txt)
       record=$(grep -io "$title\:" BookDB.txt
       if [ "$result_title" != "" ] && [ "$result_title" == "$result_title" ] && [ "$author" == "" ]
       then
       title=$(echo "$result_title" | cut -f 1 -d ":")
       author=$(echo "$result_title" | cut -f 2 -d ":")
       price=$(echo "$result_title" | cut -f 3 -d ":")
       qty_ava=$(echo "$result_title" | cut -f 4 -d ":")
       qty_sold=$(echo "$result_title" | cut -f 5 -d ":")
       echo ""
       echo "Found" $record "records:"
       echo ""
       echo -e  "$title\t$author\t"\$"$price\t$qty_ava\t$qty_sold"
       fi
```

Comment: Show us the input for this script.

Comment: Could you please post a sample input of BookDB.txt. I think this code can be simplified a lot using awk to get all the info and print out your desired output.

Comment: hi i added the sample input as requested sorry that i forgot

Comment: You should really show your exact script. What you have shown won't run properly. There's at least one `)` and one `}` missing. The check that the result title is equal to itself is a trifle odd too.

Answer (score 1):

A simple Awk script would be a lot more elegant and idiomatic, as well as more efficient.

```
awk -F : -v title="$title" -v author="$author" '
    tolower($1)==tolower(title) && (author=="" || tolower($2)==tolower(author)) {
        a[++i]=$1 ", " $2 ", $" $3 ", " $4 ", " $5; next }
    END { if (i) print "Found " i " records:"
        for (j=1; j<=i; ++j) print a[j] }' BookDB.txt
```

If you are willing to print the summary at the end rather than the beginning, this could be made more efficient and streamlined still.

You could write a simple Bash wrapper and save this in a directory in your `PATH`, or wrap it in a function.  I would however advise against making your functions perform user interaction, as that makes them harder to use as building blocks in more-complex scripts.

Answer (score 0):

The following script should satisfy your requirements:

```
#!/bin/bash

DB='./BookDB.txt'
TMP_FILE='/tmp/Book_Search.tmp.txt'

if [ ! -e "${TMP_FILE}" ]
then
        touch ${TMP_FILE}
fi

function search_book 
{
        echo "Enter Title: "
        read title
        echo "Enter Author: "
        read author
        if [ "${title}" = '' ] && [ "${author}" = '' ] # input test
        then
                echo 'You must provide Book Title and Author.'
        else
                grep -ise "${title}" ${DB} > ${TMP_FILE} #creates list of books matching title search criteria 
                index=0
                while read line
                do

                        title=$(echo ${line} | awk -F ":" {'print $1'})
                        author=$(echo ${line} | awk -F ":" {'print $2'})
                        price=$(echo ${line} | awk -F ":" {'print $3'})
                        qty_ava=$(echo ${line} | awk -F ":" {'print $4'})
                        qty_sold=$(echo ${line} | awk -F ":" {'print $5'})

                        query_result[${index}]=$(echo "${title}, ${author}, \$${price}, ${qty_ava}, ${qty_sold}") #creates new array element for every book matching search criteria
                        index=$(($index+1))
                done < ${TMP_FILE}
        fi

        lines=$(echo ${#query_result[@]}) #assigning lines variable the total count of array elements 
        echo "Found results: $lines"
        printf '%s\n' "${query_result[@]}" #using printf to print all array elements on new line

}

search_book
```

The script is using a temporary file in which all findings related to your search are written.
Current input test is checking if users have entered data for both inputs - book title and author but you have to change the grep entry in order to change the query result that will be written in the TMP_FILE:

```
grep -ise "${title}" ${DB} > ${TMP_FILE} #after completion of this command there would be entries matching the ${title} search criteria in the ${TMP_FILE} temp file
```

You have to change the entry above in order to match different search query.
After collecting the data in ${TMP_FILE} we are using while to read it line by line and create an array containing the formatted data we want to print after successful completion of the script.